# How can I define Rails route but not let URL access it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I define a "logout" route, then I can create a logout
button to go to that route.

But I don't want user to access this route from URL like "localhost:3000/logout", how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds to me like you want it to be a "post" route.  Are you familiar with the different types of http requests?  If not start here, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the config/routes.rb file:

```
post '/logout', to: 'auth#logout', as: 'auth_logout'
```

And you should read this: [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)